# Indent on second line of <li> text

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I need to use both discs and `list-style-type: lower-roman;` to style a list.

But because I'm using `content: "•";` in a `:before` pseudo element to create the disc effect, the second line of the `<li>` text does not line up.

Is there an easier way to do this?

eg:

```
i•Some list text which
goes onto the second line            //need this to be in line with the text above
   i  sub list text1
   ii sub list text2
```

I'm currently using

```css
ul>li:before {
    content: "•";
}
ol{
    margin-left: 24px;
}
ol, ul{
   list-style-type: lower-roman
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Some list text which goes onto the second line
       <ol>
           <li>sub list text1</li>
           <li>sub list text1</li>
       <ol>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a `padding-left` to the `ul > li` to indent it as a whole, make it's `position: relative` and use `position: absolute` and `left` on the `:before` pseudo-element to adjust the horizontal position of the "•" in relation to the left end of the `li`:

```css
ul>li {
  padding-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

ul>li:before {
  content: "•";
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
}

ol {
  margin-left: 24px;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style-type: lower-roman
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some list text which goes onto the second line. Some list text which goes onto the second line. Some list text which goes onto the second line
    <ol>
      <li>sub list text1</li>
      <li>sub list text1</li>
      <ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use list-style-position

```css
ul>li:before {
    content: "•";
    margin-right:5px;

    
}
ul{
    list-style-position: inside;
}
ol{
    margin-left: 24px;
    list-style-position: outside;  /* or NOT, it depends on what you like  to do */
}
ol, ul{
   list-style-type: lower-roman
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Some list text which goes onto the second linegoes onto the second linegoes onto the second linegoes onto the second linegoes onto the second linegoes onto the second line
       <ol>
           <li>sub list text1</li>
           <li>sub list text1</li>
       <ol>
   </li>
</ul>
```